# How does the compiler determine which messages can be sent to an id type variable?

Tags: objective-c, ios, compiler-construction

I've come across this 'problem' (it's not really a problem, I merely was astonished that that was possible) while trying some things with TabBarController template in Xcode. If you use the template without storyboarding the basic setup looks like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2];

self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

The viewControllers property of the tabBarController is an NSArray. Thus `[self.tabBarController objectAtIndex:0]` returns an `id`.

So I always thought if I wanted to call a method I declared at f.e. the FirstViewController class, I had to do it like this:

```
FirstViewController *firstVC = (FirstViewController *)[self.tabBarController objectAtIndex:0];
[firstVC someMethod];
```

But as it turned out, that unnecessary, the complier would also let me do the following - AS LONG AS I import a header file which declares `someMethod` (of course it doesn't necessarily increase readability, but anyway):

```
[[self.tabBarController objectAtIndex:0] someMethod];
```

I wasn't expecting this at all. So I'm assuming the compiler will allow calling any method on `id` as long as that method is declared in any class in scope of the current class (by that I mean, it's header file is imported into the current class). If the class declaring `someMethod` is not imported, the compiler will throw an error (But I have to add that I tested this while using ARC. It may very well be possible, that the compiler doesn't complain about calling 'unimported' methods on `id` when not using ARC)...

Is that assumption correct? And if possible could you provide some more information or reference about the id type?

Or did the compiler allow calling any method on `id` (imported or not) before ARC, and the complaint now for unimported methods is just a result of ARC?

Thx alot.

Comment: Actually, with objective-c you can add new methods to an object at runtime, so the compiler isn't aware of that anyway. You should check if an object supports that specific method before calling it with `if ([obj respondsToSelector:...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or did the compiler allow calling any method on id (imported or not) before ARC, and the complaint now for unimported methods is just a result of ARC?

This is correct. Without ARC it was a warning. With ARC, it's an error (because ARC can get into serious problems if it guesses wrong here).

In some cases this behavior can cause some very subtle bugs with or without ARC. If there are multiple method signatures that match the selector, then the compiler may choose the wrong return type, and this can cause very surprising runtime behavior. Matt Gallagher provides a very good explanation of this in ["A big weakness in Objective-C's weak typing."](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2011/06/big-weakness-of-objective-c-weak-typing.html) I've encountered the same bug he's describing, and it's something ObjC developers should be aware of even though it doesn't come up that often.

Comment: That a really interesting link! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Objects (type `id` is typically any instance of any object that inherits from `NSObject`)  have methods. An object either responds to a method signature, or it doesn't.

XCode may throw warning at you about this doesn't respond to that method via type checking, but the code will still run.  And if you execute a method on an object that doesn't support it, you get a runtime exception. You could cast any object, as any other type of totally incompatible object, and still call methods of that object at runtime.

```
// This should work at runtime, but generate warning when compiled
// Don't do this, obviously, but it should "work"
NSNumber *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"foobar"];
NSLog([array objectAtIndex:0]); // "foobar"
```

Type checking instances and the methods being called on them is a benefit to the programmer at compile time, but not as much to the compiled application at runtime.

So to answer your question:

> How does the compiler determine which messages can be sent to an object?

It asks the object at runtime.

```
[myObj myMethod:123];
```

Triggers something like this psuedocode in the ObjC runtime:

```
if myObj responds to the message with signature "myMethod:"?
  send myObj the "myMethod:" message with arguments [123]
else
  throw an exception
```

The type declared by the variable does not actually matter at all at runtime, because the variable is just a pointer to an object. Figuring out if that object responds to a certain method is not done at compile time.

Comment: Ok thx, I get that. But in my test I have class called TestClass that implements a method called 'test'. When I try to use `[[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] test];` without importing the `TestClass.h` it won't let me build it. (ARC semantic issue). So I'm guessing this would work without ARC, but since ARC needs to know about the method implementations to do proper memory management, it fails without importing the `TestClass.h`.

Comment: My info may be a bit out of date, I havent done much with ARC. But this is how it worked back in the day. :)